# Way of approaching categorical data in k-means clustering algorithm in python

Tags: python, k-means, categorical-data

I am facing the following problem. I I have a csv file with the following fields

```
vendor, number_of_products, price, shipping_country
```

which I am trying to cluster using python and k-means from sci-kit. The main problem I have is the way of dealing with categorical data (more specific the field `shipping_country` which contains strings of countries). 
My intention is to assign weights to the `shipping_country` field. My initial thought was to substitute each country with a number from 1-20 (with 1 being "stronger" than 20 - Worldwide -->1 , Panama -->20 for example). The problem with this approach is that it is not scientific valid (or at least I have not been able to prove so). Does anyone have any suggestion? I would really appreciate a coding example (if possible) due to the time pressure! I am using python. Thank you in advance!

Comment: what library are you using for k-means clustering, and why do you think the countries need to be weighted?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: I am using the scikit -learn. Firstly, it is not possible to use kmeans with strings. Then I thought that the `shipping_country` should play a role to determining the power of a vendor : someone who ships worldwide is more powerful to someone shipping only to one country. Nevertheless, at this point it is more important to find a way to include the `shipping_country` to the clustering procedures so I am open to suggestions.

Comment: It sounds like you want one-hot encoding more than weighting. If you edit the question as described in the links @Prune provided I can help you figure this out.

Comment: You are right. Completely ignored the guidelines - hopes this is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I don't think that you necessarily want to weight that column. What you want (I think) is a way for the categories to be numeric. This can be accomplished in sci-kit learn via one-hot encoding. In pandas, this is done with pd.get_dummies().

I'll show you how this works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'nums' : [1, 4, 6, 7],
                   'colors': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']})

df
Out[21]: 
   nums  colors
     1     red
     4    blue
     6   green
     7  yellow

pd.get_dummies(df)
Out[22]: 
   nums  colors_blue  colors_green  colors_red  colors_yellow
     1            0             0           1              0
     4            1             0           0              0
     6            0             1           0              0
     7            0             0           0              1
```

Now, for each category that was in 'colors' we have a new column with a binary indicator. However, there is too much information here. When you are dealing with prediction/regression, you have to worry about multicollinearity, which is caused by redundant information in your set of predictors.

In this case, we could infer that a color was blue, if all the other indicators are 0. In other words, we don't need the colors_blue column to indicate blueness, we can infer that from information contained in the other columns.

For these reason, you may wish to add the argument `drop_first=True`, as is done below.

```
pd.get_dummies(df, drop_first=True)
Out[23]: 
   nums  colors_green  colors_red  colors_yellow
     1             0           1              0
     4             0           0              0
     6             1           0              0
     7             0           0              1
```

Without knowing your specific use-case, I can't tell you which to use. However, I think it in most cases it is likely that you do want to drop one of your categorical columns

Comment: This exactly what I wanted. With respect to the `drop_first` I think it 'd be for my benefit to use it since I have a list of almost 15 countries - a column less.